# dojo 1.9: what annotation does declare.safeMixin add?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have been reading through the [dojo 1.9](http://dojotoolkit.org/) documentation about [`declare.safeMixin()`](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/_base/declare.html#safemixin), focusing on the difference between it and [`lang.mixin`](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/_base/lang.html#dojo-base-lang-mixin).

Here is the explanation I found...

> safeMixin() is a function defined in dojo/declare. It has the same functionality as dojo/_base/lang::mixin(), but additionally it annotates all copied methods compatibly with dojo/declare. This decoration can affect how this.inherited() works in mixed-in methods.

I can follow the [example](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/_base/declare.html#safemixin) but it doesn't really explain exactly what is added and where, can anyone give any further examples of what annotation is added to each copied method?

So to be clear, I'm not asking for an explanation of inheritance, I'm just asking specifically about the annotations added by using `declare.safeMixin()` instead of `lang.mixin`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`safeMixin` adds the `nom` property to functions that are mixed in to the target. This property is set to the key from the source object that the function was assigned to. e.g. if you call `declare.safeMixin(target, { foo: function() {} })`, the `nom` property for that function is "foo". This is necessary for `this.inherited(arguments)` to automatically figure out that it should call the parent "foo". The alternative to using `safeMixin` would be to explicitly specify the name of the parent function: `this.inherited('foo', arguments);`.

Answer (score 4):

Using `safeMixin` allows you to mix functions into an instance that can take advantage of `this.inherited` the same way that prototype methods defined using `declare` can.

For example, the following will log 2 messages:

```
require([
    "dojo/_base/lang",
    "dojo/_base/declare"
], function(lang, declare){
    var A = declare(null, {
        method: function () {
            console.log('method in prototype');
        }
    });
    var a = new A();

    declare.safeMixin(a, {
        method: function () {
            this.inherited(arguments);
            console.log('method in instance');
        }
    });

    a.method();
});
```

Without `safeMixin`, you wouldn't be able to call `this.inherited(arguments)` from the overriding method (at least, not without additional parameters) - you'd end up getting an error:

```
Error: declare: can't deduce a name to call inherited()
```