# What is the difference between mixin() and safeMixin() in dojo?

Tags: dojo, mixins, difference

Can anyone please explain the difference between `lang.mixin()` and `declare.safeMixin()`?

As per my understanding, both methods are used to **mix the objects together** and returns the target, so I don't find any difference.

Can someone explain in details?

Comment: see [link](https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/augmenting_objects/) for details.

Comment: possible duplicate of [dojo 1.9: what annotation does declare.safeMixin add?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20123183/dojo-1-9-what-annotation-does-declare-safemixin-add)